# Agora.io: leave all user when host user leave

Tags: agora.io, videocall, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am using ***agora.io*** for video call (1 to 1 video call). But I need to all user should leave (video stream should stop, as like leave buttion click) when my host user leave. I have read all documentation but I did not found any solution. I have tried banned user API call but it is not working as my specification.
If any one know the ways to leave all user when host user leave please help me.
I am appriciate any kind of help or clue.
Advance Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you're going to have to get crafty with Agora callbacks and internal logic to do this.

To determine the host UID, you can use `SetClientRole()` or `OnClientRoleChangedHandler()`

Listen if the host has left using `OnUserOfflineHandler()` using the host's UID.
If "host", then tell every user to LeaveChannel()

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when the host is not there or has left the stream, I print the message (Waiting for the host):

```
{isJoined && !isHost && remoteUid !== 0 ? (
    <React.Fragment key={remoteUid}>
      <RtcSurfaceView
          canvas={{uid: remoteUid}}
          style={styles.videoView}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
) : (
    <Text style={{color: colors.AppYellow}}>
        {isJoined && !isHost ? 'Waiting for the host' : ''}
    </Text>
)}
```

In your case, you need to hit the method of `leave()` instead of showing the text, like below:

```
const leave = () => {
    try {
        agoraEngineRef.current?.leaveChannel();
        setRemoteUid(0);
        setIsJoined(false);
        setShowComments(false);
        showMessage('You left the channel');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```